# RS-485 using USART or UART port on STM32

Tags: stm32, uart, rs485, 3.3v

On STM32F405 MCUs there are USART ports as well as UART ports available. If I need to implement RS-485 communication then which one of these should be used, USART or UART? Or are both of them equally good for RS-485 communication?

I have searched through the datasheet as well as reference manual for the MCU, but it does not provide additional information regarding the RS-485 implementation.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with "`3.3v`"? How is this relevant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter as even if you're using a USART (which provides an additional CLK pin for synchronous operation) you'll only be using the UART part (RXD/TXD). Keep in mind that you'll need an additional pin for the Data Enable signal.

Comment: If you use full-duplex RS485, then you don't need a data enable signal. You only need one for half-duplex RS485

Comment: @Toor For practical purposes, RS-485 without data enable signal would be RS-422.